# Having trouble with same-site cookie and redirect from external website

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, samesite

I have implemented a same-site cookie which we use as SSO for our 3 webapplication.
When using them all with eachother it works perfectly.

However we have an external CRM where we link to a user in one of our applications and whenever I redirect from that the redirect link is set to cross-site and no longer reads the authentication cookie as it should

How can I fix this problem??

More info:

We have a CRM with a link to our permalink project (this project has no authentication), which in turn redirects to our portal where they can view extra settings on a user which are unavailable in our CRM.
Since the origin was from our CRM (not in the same domain) all requests after that are set to "Cross-site" instead of "same-site" or "none" and this is not stopping us from using this redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently it was as simple as setting samesite to lax instead of strict.